# Fazer 3 buscas simultaneas na mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possível realizar 3 buscas simultaneas em uma mesma tabela.  A situação é a seguinte: tenho uma tabela que contém digamos as colunas:

Carro, Material, IP, data

Daí tenho que buscar:

```
1 - Quantos carros foram cadastrados na ultima hora
2 - Quantos Materiais foram cadastrados na última 2 horas
3 - Quantos Ips acessaram nos últimos 30 minutos
```

é possível eu realizar essas 3 buscas simultaneas, onde tenho que retornar o número de dados encontrado em cada uma delas.

A maneira que faço é seguinte:

```
$conn->prepare("QUERY 1");
$conn->prepare("QUERY 2");
$conn->prepare("QUERY 3");
```

Eu chamo o prepare 3 vezes, eu gostaria de minimizar isso, chamar apenas uma vez e retornar o número de dados separados pelo número de ocorrência:

```
Query 1= 10 
Query 2= 15
Query 3= 17
```

Isso é possível ou terei que buscar da maneira que faço atualmente, tudo separadamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subquery no from parece ser uma alternativa:

```
SELECT a.carros, b.materiais, c.ips FROM 
    (SELECT carros ...) AS a, 
    (SELECT materiais ...) AS b, 
    (SELECT ips ...) AS c
```

Espero ter auxiliado, abraço

Comment: Cara realmente acredito que este seja o caminho, mas estou tendo entendendo, como separar o que desejo contar entende: `SELECT COUNT(a.user_tentativa) FROM (SELECT * FROM tentativas_login WHERE email_tentativa = 'comando@hotmail.com')  AS a`, dessa maneira ele retorna certo, mas na hora que adicona outro select, ele acaba retornando tudo.

Comment: @abcd coloque os `count(*) AS label` nos subselects e coloque nos campos do select principal somente o labels que vai dar certo.

Comment: Desculpa, tentei fazer da seguinte maneira: `"SELECT b, a FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tentativas_login WHERE email_tentativa = 'comando@hotmail.com')  AS a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tentativas_login WHERE user_tentativa = 'jhon1') AS b"`

Comment: Sou bem fraco, em sql, geralmente faço apenas SELECTS fáceis... Ele não retorna nada...

Comment: @abcd nos campos do select principal você precisa colocar o label e o campo que você quer trazer, assim: `SELECT b.tentativa_b, a.tentativa_a FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS tentativa_a FROM tentativas_login WHERE email_tentativa = 'comando@hotmail.com')  AS a, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS tentativa_b FROM tentativas_login WHERE user_tentativa = 'jhon1') AS b`

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certinho, agora irei implementar da maneira que desejo. ATT

Answer (score 5):

Uma saída com mysqli é usar *multi query*.

Segue um exemplo da própria **[documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php)**:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Notas:

- `mysqli_store_result()`Transfere um set de resultados da query ativa
- `mysqli_next_result()` Prepara o próximo resultado de multi_query
- `mysqli_more_results()` Verifica se há mais algum resultado de uma multi query a ser processado